# Match relative URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

https://github.com/sorensen/absolutify implemented a nice Regex pattern to match relative URLs:

```
/(=["'])(([.]+\/)|(?:\/)|(\w|\#))(?!\/)/g
```

While this pattern matches paths correctly, it won't match relative files (like in `<a href="index.html">foo</a>`)

What would an optimised, elegant Regex look like, that matches relative files but not valid URLs like `//example.com`, `http://example.com`, `https://example.com/foo`, etc?

Comment: how it doesn't match? `var str = '="index.html"'; console.log('matches? ' + str.match(/(=["'])(([.]+\/)|(?:\/)|(\w|\#))(?!\/)/g));`

Answer (score 0):

I found the implementation of [X-Ray's Absolutes Module](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray/blob/master/lib/absolutes.js) a nice solution if you can depend on Cheerio or jQuery.